# Version of gcc on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

I'm using some inline functions in my code and gcc.gnu.org says there are major differences in semantics until gcc 4.3. I want to use gcc 4.4+ but I have no idea how to achieve that on my Mac. This is the output of gcc -v:

```
$ gcc -v
  Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr 
  --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
  Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
  Thread model: posix
```

From this I assume I have gcc 4.2.1 - is that right? How do I get a newer one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

```
$ brew tap homebrew/versions
$ brew update
$ brew install gcc48
```

Answer (score 3):

You can install a new version using homebrew or macports. I believe that the versions keg has gcc in it. You can install your desired version using

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install gcc44
```

Comment: It `brew` not `homebrew`.

Comment: Oh my bad that is a typo

Comment: Great, I already used homebrew so I know the syntax. Thanks for your help.